# How to allow rewind but disable fast-forwarding in html5-video

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have the following code (using videojs)

```
this.on("timeupdate", function(event) {
            previousTime = this.currentTime();
        });

        this.on("seeking", function(){
            if (this.currentTime() > previousTime){
                this.currentTime = previousTime;
            }
        });
```

Problem is that, once you try to fast-forward one time, it no longers keeps track of the timeupdate on the progress bar. I can not longer seek on the bar - not even rewind the video. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, these are not standard HTMLMediaElement methods and properties, so I'm assuming you're using some kind of framework, perhaps [Popcorn.js](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js)? And I'm assuming `this` refers to the object wrapping your video element.

The problem is that you're overwriting the `currentTime` method. If you were to reference the video element directly, then you would seek the way you're doing it, by setting the `currentTime` property, like: `videoElement.currentTime = previousTime`. But since you're using the framework, `this.currentTime` is supposed to be a function until you change it to a number.

To demonstrate, modify your code as follows:

```
this.on("seeking", function(){
    console.log(typeof this.currentTime); // 'function'
    if (this.currentTime() > previousTime){
        this.currentTime = previousTime;
        console.log(typeof this.currentTime); // 'number'
    }
});
```

The next time you run the "timeupdate" handler, the call to `this.currentTime()` will throw an error because it is no longer a function.

You can probably fix it like this (assuming you're using Popcorn or something that works similarly):

```
this.on("seeking", function(){
    if (this.currentTime() > previousTime){
        this.currentTime(previousTime);
    }
});
```

You'll also want to make sure that you don't set `previousTime` while seeking, since "timeupdate" may fire before "seeking" does. I'm not sure how to do that with your framework, so here's a link to a working example using the native HTMLVideoElement API:

http://jsbin.com/kilemoto/1/edit

Comment: Yeah, I'm using videojs... Wow why did I not mention that... Sorry edited it... And yes, I can't believe how such small change made all the difference... Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Just had to implement this, seems to be working nicely

```
var elem = document.querySelector("video");
let previousTime = 0;

elem.ontimeupdate = function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    previousTime = elem.currentTime;
  }, 1000)
}

elem.onseeking = function() {
  if (elem.currentTime > previousTime) {
      elem.currentTime = previousTime;
  }
}
```